Screenshot of the Week #113
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 113th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Clockwork's picture from kirby-dream-land-3 won with 10 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-04-15, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-04-22, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No theme
There's no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

I think this is the first time I see 3 answers in a tie for now.

@Clockwork I hate ties, but I can't solve it because I already voted them all lol

Same. Sometimes I feel like I should stop voting because I almost always vote everything x) /s

hm which to upvote too?

Heading to the theater in princess-peach-showtime


For some reasons, I thought the statues were depicting Captain Olimar's species. Or Moogles from Kingdom Hearts.

@Clockwork Aren't Moogles from Final Fantasy?

@EmCeeChupitheUndying Yeah, but the shape of the ones from Kingdom Hearts are very peculiar, with the round nose that looks a lot like the statues in this screenshot in my opinion.

oh cool (Doesn't play Kingdom Hearts)

Sneakily watching the sun set in valheim


Playing hide 'n' seek with the sun, are we?



the-elder-scrolls-online

Thumbs up to the umbrella ghosts in ghostwire-tokyo.


Akira Toriyama, addressing his children in the game chrono-trigger.


Not much to show, but considering what happened recently, I thought it would be an appropriate submission.

Is this screenshot stretched? It looks wider than it should be.

@Stevoisiak Possibly. It might be because of my resolution settings.

You guys play some strange games lol. Reminds me of Commodore 64 games. Or Megadrive, maybe.

@n00dles That's close, this game was released on SNES and re-released on various consoles (I think Playstation 1, DS, Switch?). A huge majority of my favourite games come from the SNES era.

Ah, I never had Nintendo consoles. Now I see why you play them, though.

There's also been a Steam re-release (I should get around to playing that some time, haven't gotten very far in it).

@DanielSchepler It's one of those rare games in which the leveling is so consistent, you don't even need to grind as you progress through the story (although you could if you wanted to).

I played it on DS. It was a great game; this i want to see as an hd remake.

A new adventure is waiting for zidane and the others. final-fantasy-9 on switch.


I love this game

I played it very often and it was my 1. final fantasy. I bought it used.
